# How do I know if the STIBP slow patches were backported to my ubuntu kernel?

Tags: kernel

This article https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-420wip-stibp&num=1 discusses the performance impact of recent STIBP patches were released in kernel 4.19 and backported to LTS kernels. 
The result was apparently to basically turn off hyperthreading, bad for Intel CPUs.

Then,  changes were made in the last few days so that the performance impact is much lower by only applying this mitigation when it is most likely to reduce an actual security threat.

How can I tell if recent ubuntu kernels have the 4.19 STIBP patch backported  (bad performance) or if they have also had the recent improvements backported, or if the 4.19 changes never made it to the ubuntu kernels at all?

I use 18.04.1 mainly, but I have the 4.18 generic-hwe prerelease kernel.